# Trying to get my logic terminology straight

Tags: logic, terminology, definition, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around the specific definitions of things when it comes to logic. This is my current understanding from my own note-taking, can anyone correct me?

Expressions: $2+2$, for example. Any sequence of mathematical symbols which produce some mathematical object like a number, matrix, function, set, etc.

Statements: Usually made up of expressions and must evaluate to either **true** or **false**. Statements must be well-formed. Not invoking undefined behavior like $0/0=1$ or bad syntax like $==3++-4=-$. So $2+2=4$ is a true statement, $2+2=5$ is a false statement. Statements are allowed to contain words and properties, e.g. "$30+7$ is prime".

Relations: Symbols like $=$, $<$, $\leq$, $\in$, $\subset$, etc, which provide some relationship between expressions to create a statement.

Properties: Is prime, is continuous, is invertible, etc.

Logical Connectives: And, or, not, if-then, implies, if-and-only-if, etc. These connect statements to create "compound statements" which are themselves still statements.

Compound Statement: For statements $P$ and $Q$, things like $P \land Q$, $P \lor Q$, $P \implies Q$, $P \iff Q$, etc.

Proposition: I don't really understand the difference between this and a statement but I am guessing $2+2=4$ is also a proposition, or something like "John has brown hair."

Predicate: Like a proposition but with variables, may be true or false depending on the value of the variable. For example $P(x) = x + 2 = 5$ is true when $x=3$ and false otherwise.

Quantifier: The universal quantifier $\forall$, or the existential quantifier $\exists$.

Universe: The relevant set of objects we draw from, referred to via quantifiers. For example $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}$ means "for all $x$ in the natural numbers", the natural numbers here would be the universe.

Is my understanding correct so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty good. Personally, I would do 'predicates' a little different.  The $P$ would be the predicate, while $P(x)$ would be a formula.

Also, you can regard properties as $1$-place predicates, and relations as $n$-place predicates. For example, $\le$ is a $2$-place predicate, and $\le(x,y)$ would be a formula using that predicate. ... though we will often use the infix notation $x \le y$ instead.

Indeed, the notion of a 'formula' is important but missing from your list. You can create Atomic formulas by giving an $n$-place predicate $n$ terms, which can either be constants (like $1$), variables (like $x$), or complex terms (like $x+1$).  Atomic formulas can be combined using logical connectives into 'compound formulas', and formulas can be quantified.

Statements are formulas that do not have free (i.e. unquantified) variables).

Comment: If $P$ is a predicate but $P(x)$ is not then how would one even "state" or "frame" or "express" $P$ by itself?

Comment: @user539262 You typically provide a little 'legend' .. saying that $P(x)$ means '$x$ has property ...'

Comment: Where do quantifiers fit in exactly? Do they transform things into a set? Are they an intrinsic part of predicates? Can they apply to statements or propositions?

Comment: @user539262 Quantifiers do not transform  things into sets, nor are they an inherent part of predicates. Syntactically, you put a quantifier in front of a formula, but what you quantify is of course some variable; that is, by putting $\forall x$ in front of a formula $\phi$, all free variables $x$ occurring in $\phi$ get quantified. The result of a quantification is always a new formula, but it could become a statement if thanks to the quantification there are no more free variables.

Comment: So would $P(x) = (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) \land (x > 5)$ be a quantified predicate? Would $P(x) = (x > 5)$ be an unquantified predicate?

Comment: @user539262 That first one is a little weird with the $\land$ in there ... do you mean $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(x >5)$?  Anyway, I would avoid talking about 'quantified predicates' or 'unquantified predicates', but rather quantified (or unquantified) variables.

Comment: I am just trying to understand how things are stated and how they are not stated, what they're called, how they're used, etc. In this case you are putting two things next to each other with no logical connectives in the predicate? What is this called?

Comment: @user539262 It's a formula and, since the only variable is quantified, it's also a statement. And, since the last operation we performed was a universal quantification, we sometimes call the statement itself a universal statement.

Comment: Now I am even more lost, lol. I can't tell when something is a statement or a predicate or if something is a true/false claim or what. Is there a good book that goes over all this stuff with examples in greater detail?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page on First-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) is pretty good, actually.